# How to remove labels in Prometheus Alert template?

Tags: prometheus, go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

I found a template for Prometheus Alert Manager for alerts, but I receive many unnecessary labels in notification. How to remove labels in template? This code is responsible for labels (look below). I tried to set conditions in If operator, but it didnt help. I dont have deep knowledge in Go Templating system & Json, so I'm asking for help. I use Amazon Prometheus.

```
{{ if gt (len $alerts.Labels.SortedPairs) 0 -}},
"labels": 
    {{ "{" }}
        {{ range $index, $label := $alerts.Labels.SortedPairs }}
            {{ if $index }}, 
            {{ end }}
            "{{ $label.Name }}": "{{ $label.Value }}"
        {{ end }}
    {{ "}" }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [here](https://hodovi.cc/blog/creating-awesome-alertmanager-templates-for-slack/), you can filter labels by name something like this.

```
    {{- range .CommonLabels.SortedPairs -}}
        {{- if ne .Name "alertname" -}}
            {{- .Name }}%3D"{{- .Value -}}"%2C%20
        {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `.CommonLabels` and `.Labels` in Alertmanager are of type [KV](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/notifications/#kv).

This type has a `Remove` method, which takes a slice of strings and returns the KV map without these keys.

So you can skip multiple unwanted labels like this:

```
{{ range (.CommonLabels.Remove (stringSlice "key1" "key2" "key3")).SortedPairs }}
    {{- .Name }}: {{ .Value }}
{{ end }}
```